# use restful web services without losing HTML representation

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have created a spring MVC application that uses JMX to collect JVM informations.
Now i want to represent these JVM informations in graphical form within my Views by sending JSON files from the collector to the user machine.
The problem is that:

- Using Rest Controllers will return JSON files.

But i want to use my controllers to return view and in the same time i want these views to receive JSON files.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You will get better responses to questions if you can narrow it down to some specific code/lines and to explicitly ask a question about one particular thing. As explained in the guides, [learn how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a controller which returns the HTML page, and then load the data with AJAX, using another controller, which returns the JSON data.